# Life shortened by telling tithi

Tags: panchang, life-span

Why does life shorten by telling tithi?

> If asked, one should not say what the lunation is on a particular day. By telling it, one's life becomes shortened.

> tithiṃ pakṣasya na brūyāt tathāsyāyur na riṣyate

[source](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b069.htm)

Comment: Not only that it says one should not tell which Paksha either. Now tithi, paksha of the particular day or the tithi, paksha one is born in?

Comment: You probably right. This may be about one's birth date and not today's tithi/paksha. @rickross

Comment: Okay .... @Kanthri